# Apache AuthType Basic for local network, no auth for the rest

Tags: apache-2.2

I tried to find a solution, but my case is the opposite of most configurations and it's getting hard to find examples.

I have a php application who looks for the typical HTTP Authentication first, and in case it fails (No REMOTE_USER var found), it shows a login screen to authenticate against a local user file. I cannot modify this php app.

I need to configure apache's authentication to match this scenerario:
If the remote IP matches our network ip range (let's say 192.168.0), require an AuthType Basic to access the page.
If the remote IP it's not in our range (the rest of the internet), skip the AuthType Basic and show the page directly, so the php app will not found the REMOTE_USER variable and it will show his own login page.

Is that possible? I found plenty of examples doing exactly the opposite (asking for Apache Auth if you're not on the company network) but I don't see any matching my case.

I was modifying this example:

```
<Directory /home/www/site1/private>
  AuthUserFile /home/www/site1-passwd
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName MySite
  Require valid-user
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from 192.168.0
  Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

It would be great to specify "Allow from !(172.17.10)", but I don't think this is possible. So I'm pretty sure I need to play around with the Allow, Deny, and Order directives, but I still didn't find a solution.

Anyone who faced a similar situation?
Thanks!

Comment: Finally I fixed it using a proxypass. Depending on the source IP, the proxy will redirect the petition to one URL or another.

Thanks to all for the answers!

Answer (score -2):

Can you try this.

```
Order allow,deny
 Deny from 192.168.0
 Allow from All
 Satisfy any
```

Comment: That only blocks users from 192.168.0.0/24 and does not offer basic Auth for them